# Ibm MQ - MQCONNX ended with reason code 2035

Tags: ibm-mq

I'm setting an Mq server for learning purposes, which I call it QM1. So, I try aiming at the queue by typing in cmd:

```
amqsputc DEV.QUEUE.1 QM1
```

After asking for my password, it returns: `MQCONNX ended with reason code 2035`

I have set my local user and Win 10 group and after shuffling trhough MQ 9 documentation, here is my workaround attempts:

1. `setmqaut -m QM1 -t qmgr -p app +connect`  (app is my user)
2. Included *app* tn my mqm group.

It still returns code 2035

Comment: There is a file called `AMQERR01.LOG` under the queue manager named directory under `%MQ_FILE_PATH%`.  Look in this file to see what error is presented when you get the 2035 response.  If you had to give `+connect` to the queue manager then likely you need to give `+put` to the queue.

Comment: amq5542i the failed authentication check was caused by the queue manager. I tried disabling this check, since the purpose is only testing (ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH(DISABLED)). Still does not work.

Comment: And NOW what dies the AMQERR01.LOG say? It will have a different error message now.

Comment: It would be helpful if you edited your question and pasted the `AMQERR01.LOG` errors with the same time stamp (there will be more than one) from before you set `CHLAUTH(DISABLED)` and after.

Comment: @wes85melis [this cheat sheet](https://developer.ibm.com/components/ibm-mq/articles/mq-dev-cheat-sheet/) outlines debugging for MQRC 2035. For Windows the path for the `AMQERR01.LOG` log file, assuming a recent IBM MQ version and default install, will likely be `C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ`. It looks like you configured your QM with the developer config and maybe adapted [these instructions for Ubuntu](https://developer.ibm.com/components/ibm-mq/tutorials/mq-connect-app-queue-manager-ubuntu/). It would be worth checking you completed all of Step 5. specifically, the `setmqaut` commands.